# access_token not present in the passport-github2 request

Tags: node.js, github, oauth-2.0, passport.js, github-api

I have registered an OAuth App via my Github account. I am basically trying to authorize my `node` requests(by sending `access_token` as part of request cookies) so I can access few APIs on another server. Hence I am using the [`github-passport2`](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github) package. I have setup the github strategy etc. & it seems to be all according to the doc. The flow works well too.

**My Issue**

After logging into Github(authorized) & getting redirected back to my `/auth/github/callback`, I **ideally should be authorized and should have an `access_token` in the `req`. But I don't have it!** Because of this I am not able to authorize my future requests with an `access_token`.

Important to note is that, this `access_token` is automatically attached when the request is initiated from a browser/client(using `withCredentials: true` parameter). The same `access_token` via node doesn't seem to be retrievable.

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/github/callback",
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github', { scope: [ 'user:email' ] }), function(req, res){
  // The request will be redirected to GitHub for authentication, so this
  // function will not be called.
});

app.get('/auth/github/callback', passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req); // <- This ideally should have the access_token? but doesn't
});
```

I have struggling for days on this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is deprecation warning on GitHub OAuth page - https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/ - are you sure you are not trying to access field that doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: @Sindis - I'm not really making use of any `token` parameter. So I'm not really sure what to make of the api changes.

Comment: @Sindis My login/authorize requests seem to be going to `https://github.com/login/oauth...` and not the new v3 API